# Hypothesis test with parameter uncertainty

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, least-squares

Basic problem but I can't seem to figure out how to think about this:

In a simple OLS problem  the estimate of parameter $\beta$ is $\beta^*=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$.

Then, the standard error of $\beta^*$ is $s (X'X)_{jj}^{-1/2}$.

But $s^2$ is uncertain. It has a probability distribution. Let's assume for now that we actually know the true value of the variance of $s^2$ (ignoring the fact that this relies on knowing $\sigma$, which would render this whole exercise pointless).

My question is:
How can we incorporate the uncertain nature of the standard error measurement into the p-value calculation for the hypothesis test?  In econometrics class the professor basically just showed that $s^2$ was an unbiased estimate for $\sigma^2$ and therefore it was ok to use the above standard error formula for the test, but I'm skeptical. Was he right?

Comment: Hint: did the professor use a Normal distribution function or a Student t distribution function to compute the p-value?

Comment: Thanks! Missed this connection the first time, now it should stick...